# python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1

Tags: installation, pip, package

I'm trying to instal clawpack [Link](https://www.clawpack.org/installing_pip.html#installing-pip) and when I run the pip install, it keeps returning with the above issue. I've updated my pip (`v23.2.1`) and setuptools (`68.2.2`) as some have on suggested on other posts.

I ran `$ pip install clawpack`
and the returning error was:

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['pyclaw', 'riemann', 'visclaw', 'geoclaw', 'amrclaw', 'classic', 'clawutil', 'clawpack'].
      
      To avoid accidental inclusion of unwanted files or directories,
      setuptools will not proceed with this build.
```

Comment: https://github.com/clawpack/clawpack/issues/211 , https://github.com/clawpack/clawpack/pull/212

Comment: @phd that did it, thank you so much for posting those links!